# Synchronizing two ListViews using Pinterest ListView

Tags: android, pinterest

I have two `listview` and I want to `synchronize` them. I have tried pinterest listview but cannot put `onItemClickListener` ,I also cannot use staggered grid view and scroll view.

Please suggest any alternatives

Comment: what do u mean by synchronize two listview ?

Comment: the list views that i am using have different no of elements i want that the list view should end at same point

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you can use [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html)
instead with [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) as a Layout manager.

Something like:

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
// specify an adapter
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Read more here:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Or you can use a bit "old-style" staggered grid view library (Android SDK 8+)

[StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView)

Comment: i tried this but this requires external libraries and higher api level. is there any solution by which i can run the application even on api level 8

Comment: Check https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView this library. I've been using it and it's really good. Support Android 2.2+(Android SDK 8+) Added to my initial answer.

Comment: thanks but it still uses external library. is there something by which i can synchronize the ending of the the two listviews

Comment: You don't want to use two listviews, believe me. It ineffective, painful and, by doing this, you are not balancing the height of content in each of them, so it can easily be, that one is much shorter, than another.  External libraries are our friends, give them a try :)